# load average is too high

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, cpu-load

i installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. Even if when I am doing nothing, load average is somewhere between 0.50 to 0.60.

laptop configuration is
 toshiba satellite c640
 Intel Core i5-2430M (2.3Ghz, 3MB L2 Cache)
 6GB Ram

How can I make sure all drivers are installed properly? or how to get to root of the problem?

Comment: You can find out which processes are using your cpu via top in the commandline and the graphical system monitor tool.(don't know the correct english term but it is installed by default as far as I know and the ICon looks like an EKG the binary is called gnome-system-monitor)

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue, I have reported it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/985661). Don't worry about it! The kernel team it is working on it already. It seems  to be some calculation problem.

Answer (score 0):

Press Super and look for System monitor to check higher processing program.

Run this command to finish your installation.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```